# Janrain Social Login fails on localhost

Tags: javascript, janrain

I have been using a java/javascript/angular login process using Janrain Social Login for a while and everything has worked well both locally and deployed to the web. A few days ago, the localhost implementation stopped working...

What happens:
 1. User clicks a login button on the webpage 
 2. Code calls Janrain's widget.init() and that all works because a login panel with 4 providers pops up. All normal to this point.
 3. I click on the Google button to log in via Google. 
 4. Pretty quickly, on localhost, a pop-up returns with 'Token URL is not whitelisted' and everything stops.

There have been no changes to the whitelist or the login code. The whitelist (on Janrain dashboard) simply has 'localhost', just as the documentation says it should.

**Does anyone have any ideas on where i should even start looking?** Janrain's documentation is not helpful.

Comment: I switched to using a LinkedIn profile on localhost and everything went back to working (except Google).

Comment: So, I conclude the Janrain code is fine (which it must be since it hasn't been changed) but the callback request to Google for localhost is failing at Google's end. Which suggests it must be some change in the oauth2 treatment at the Google-end in relation to whitelisting localhost. Which would seem to make development a virtual impossibility. Anyway, LinkedIn works.